# Does the where clause get used during the process of joining tables in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Let's say we have the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B USING (k)
WHERE A.c = 'SOME VALUE'
```

knowing that **k** and **c** are indexed columns. The question is: does MySql uses the *WHERE* clause condition while joining the two tables or does it just join them and then apply the condition. Also, how would it facilitate the usage of the index on the **c** column?

Comment: It depends on which index is expected to improve the query performance. This depends on the cardinality of each index.

Comment: It all depends on the indexes, the data histogram, and if some data is already in memory. You would need to get the actual execution plan to see what it will do at this moment, but this can change at any time without notice.

Answer (score 0):

The JOIN operation is executed before the WHERE clause [in various SQL languages](https://sqlbolt.com/lesson/select_queries_order_of_execution) (I assume also in MySQL, however couldn't find an official documentation). This means the tables are indeed created first and only then the filtering with the WHERE clause is done. Logically, you need to have a "result set"/joined table first before you can apply filter options.